# Tab View doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a simple build menu with a tabbed view.
After i changed something yesterday night it doesn't work any more.
The switch between the tabs is broken, the content of all tabs will be shown at the first tab

Snippet:

```
 <div id="builder">
    <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="tabContainer">
    <div class="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li id="tabHeader_1">Page 1</li>
        <li id="tabHeader_2">Page 2</li>
        <li id="tabHeader_3">Page 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tabscontent">
      <div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_1">
        <h2>Page 1</h2>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_2">
        <h2>Page 2</h2>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_3">
        <h2>Page 3</h2>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Sample Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Xx28B/)

[Source](http://www.my-html-codes.com/javascript-tabs-html-5-css3)

[My Test Site](http://kappss.funpic.de/world/index2.php)

Comment: `After i changed something yesterday night it doesn't work any more.` might be helpful to know what you changed?

Comment: You have jQuery UI included on the site, why not use its tabs plugin instead?

Comment: Sorry but it was 05:00am in the morning
why was the link to my test-webserver deleted? http://kappss.funpic.de/world/index2.php
I liked the design of the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `var pages = container.querySelectorAll(".tabpage");` returns a collection with length 0.

However, if you change it to `var pages = document.querySelectorAll(".tabpage");`, it works fine.

The reason is that your `.tabpage` aren't children of your `container` (which is `#tabContainer`). Look at your HTML *carefully* (from your fiddle):

```
<div id="tabContainer">  <!-- this is what you set at "container" in JS -->
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li id="tabHeader_1">Military</li>
            <li id="tabHeader_2">Supply</li>
            <li id="tabHeader_3">Research</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  <!-- .tabs -->
</div> <!-- #tabContainer -->
<div class="tabscontent">
    <div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_1"> <!-- this is NOT a child of #tabContainer -->
```

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xx28B/6/) appears to be working.

Comment: sorry but i didn't get this. I edited it at my webserver can you take a look?